# Fastest way to find correct combination with set of 8 booleans

Tags: c#, performance, boolean, combinations

I have a set of booleans:`x1, y1, z1, x2, z2, x3, y3, z3` each one is either true or false. Rather than writing dozens of if statements to check for the right true/false combo, what is the absolutely most efficient and fastest way to discover the correct combination of what is true and false?:

```
if(x1 == true && y1 == true && z1 == true && 
   x2 == true && z2 == true && 
   x3 == true && y3 == true && z3 == true)
  {
    //do stuff if this is correct combination
  }
else if(x1 == false && y1 == true && z1 == true && 
   x2 == true && z2 == true && 
   x3 == true && y3 == true && z3 == true)
  {
    //do stuff if this is correct combination
  }
 //do on and so forth for the next few dozen lines to check combo's
```

I was thinking of looping through with a for loop as well but this also seems very slow. This is going to be run dozens of times every second so I'm trying to make it as efficient as possible.

edit for clarification: y2 is purposely removed.

The reason I'm doing this is because I have a grid as follows:

```
x1, y1 ,z1
x2, y2 ,z2
x3, y3 ,z3
```

I'm trying to find if all the booleans around y2 are set to true or false because the texture applied to y2 will be different in each situation. For example, if x1, y1, and z1 are false but the rest true, y2 texture will be set to a specific image. If x3, z1, and x2 are false,  and the rest true, then again y2 will be set to a different image. I'm trying to find what items around y2 are on or off so I can set the correct texture for y2.

Comment: Just some syntax suggestion: You can remove the `== true` and only do `&& x1 && y1 && ...` **EDIT**: You could also try to use `&` instead of `&&` as `&` is a bit faster, but may take longer if the if-statement fails

Comment: Encode them into an `int` and check for the numerical value of the combination you are interested in? Should mean you encode once and then do `if (myEncodedFlags == 42)`, assuming there are only a handful of useful combinations out of all possible combinations.

Comment: Well you have 512 possible combinations (19683 if you consider FileNotFound). If each of those combinations is valid, you'll have to cater for them. Perhaps there is some pattern you can apply, for example "skip all where !x3" to reduce the possibilities.

Comment: Sorry i've updated the question to help clarify what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just convert it to a digit

```
x1 = 2^0 = 1
x2 = 2^1 = 2
x3 = 2^2 = 4
x4 = 2^3 = 8
```

you can do it for example like this:

```
int digit =
    (x1 ? 1 << 0 : 0) | (y1 ? 1 << 1 : 0) | (z1 ? 1 << 2 : 0) |
    (x2 ? 1 << 3 : 0) | (y2 ? 1 << 4 : 0) | (z2 ? 1 << 5 : 0) |
    (x3 ? 1 << 6 : 0) | (y3 ? 1 << 7 : 0) | (z3 ? 1 << 8 : 0);
```

or by using `BitArray`:

```
BitArray bits = new BitArray(new[] {x1, y1, z1, x2, y2, z2, x3, y3, z3});
int[] array = new int[1];
bits.CopyTo(array, 0);
int digit = array[0];
```

this way your combination of: false, true, true, true, true will be 01111 which is `15` decimal

you can then store your correct combination as a another digit and simply check if they are equal

Comment: Thanks, seems like a great solution. Will try this out. :)

Comment: Are you sure it's faster? With the booleans, you can do an early exit as soon as you find a wrong value. It's just basic arithmetic and jumps. This seems too much work, much more arithmetic, no early exit, and even allocating objects and giving work for the GC. Edit: okay, I see the OP wants to check for multiple combinations. Then I'd go with the first, shifting version.