# Fastest and most readable way to check three booleans

Tags: java, performance, readability

Similar to [what is the fastest algorithm for permutations of three condition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17215881/what-is-the-fastest-algorithm-for-permutations-of-three-condition) and [Fastest way to find correct combination with set of 8 booleans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20490154/fastest-way-to-find-correct-combination-with-set-of-8-booleans)

---

I have three `boolean` values (called `a`, `b`, and `c`), each of which has a different action based on which ones are true. There is one little odd situation here; if `a` is false then `c` must also be false. There are six possibilities, and this results in a rather long and ugly looking `if` statement chain. Here's what I came up with:

```
if (a)
    {
        if (b)
        {
            if (c)
            {
                doAction1(); // a = true, b = true, c = true
            }
            else
            {
                doAction2(); // a = true, b = true, c = false
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (c)
            {
                doAction3(); // a = true, b = false, c = true
            }
            else
            {
                doAction4(); // a = true, b = false, c = false
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (b)
        {
            doAction5(); // a = false, b = true, c = false
        }
        else
        {
            doAction6(); // a = true, b = false, c = false
        }
    }
```

I would prefer if the code was readable and fast, meaning that I would prefer not to use any weird bitwise operations. This isn't a homework assignment, just a simplified version of part of a personal project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can always write

```
if (a && b && c)
{
    action1 ();
}
else if (a && b && ! c)
{
    action2 ();
}
else if (a && ! b && c)
{
    action3 ();
}
else if (a && ! b && ! c)
...
```

Arguably having fewer nesting levels and fewer braces that are just noise makes it more readable. And you don't need the comments anymore.

Comment: it would be interesting to compare the resulting byte code from this version compared to the OP's original.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a && b && c){
    //a b c true
}
else if(!a && b && !c){
    //a false b true c false
}
else if(a && !b && c{
    //a true b false c true
}
//etc
```